# Access props when using the Link element and the useLocation hook from react router

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, react-router-v4

I'm trying to send props to a child component rendered with the `<Link>` tag from react router. I'm doing like this:

- This is how I use the `Link` element in the parent component (wrapped with the `useRouter` hook, though no idea if I have to):

```
[...]
<Link
  to={{
    pathname: `/Element/${id}`,
    state: {
      info: "foo",
    },
  }}
>
  {title}
</Link>;
[...]
```

- This is the component receiving that information :

```
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

const Element = () => {
  const data = useLocation();
  console.log(data)

  return (...);
};
```

This is returning an object with the key `state: undefined`

What am I missing here? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found it, I needed to wrap both components with the `withRouter` hook